# How to write .class1 > class2 {} in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

What is the best/less verbose/different/more readable way to write this code in SASS?

```
.class1 > .class2 > .class3 {...}
```

Comment: The problem here is what, exactly?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I get the question, but I don't think you get how things work here on StackOverflow.  You're supposed to have *tried* something *before* you ask questions.  See what the text says when you hover over the downvote button?  "This question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably be able to just do:

```
.class1 
    >.class2
        property:value
```

you might also use

```
& > .class2
```

or if you like your sass cssy...sassy css:

```
.class1 {
    > .class2 {...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for complete answer.